# Printer Manual Duplex Emulation?

Tags: printing, samsung, duplex-printing

My printer have Emulated Duplex Mode under Windows 7. In which it says " Turn all Papers DownSide " . But my Printer Driver in Ubuntu doesn't support long edge and short edge Duplex Emulation.

Its a Duplex Emulation, not a real Duplex Machines. It ask for Turning Paper in Reverse Order when printing.

I need similar thing for linux to save some paper. How can this be done.

**Note**
Printing Odd and Even Pages causes problem in Case of Multiple Page per Sheet.

Printer
Samsung
SCX3200 Series ( SCX 3201g )

Comment: Not all questions are answered the day they're posted. There are [other Ubuntu help resources](http://www.ubuntu.com/support), but whether or not you decide to use those now, I counsel patience. Most of us have lives outside of Ask Ubuntu, school/jobs, and other commitments. We're volunteers who can't always respond quickly to help you or anyone else (and you'll find that's true of the other free support resources). If that doesn't work for you, you might consider [buying support](http://www.ubuntu.com/business/services/overview).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the exact same problem with my HP Photosmart C3180.
You might want to try installing `gnome-manual-duplex` (assuming you are under the Gnome desktop). It is not in the repositories, but there is a .deb package [there](http://sourceforge.net/projects/g-manual-duplex/files/).

See also the presentation [here](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/gnome-manual-duplex-a-utility-that-adds-manual-duplex-to-the-print-menu.html).

Comment: Just adding some context, I'm currently running 14.04 (not yet stable) and my LaserJet 1020 was installed by default, and when I print something I get the possibility under "Page Setup" to choose two sided printing, but the terminology may be confusing. "Long Edge" and "Short Edge" refers to what edge of the paper should be to the left/right, so "Long Edge" is the standard. So as a summary, this might already be included so look for it before installing `gnome-manual-duplex`.

Comment: Doesn't install a "virtual printer" any more on Ubuntu 20.04 but can be invoked from the command line as a standalone application.

Answer (score 0):

Check this virtual printer driver:

https://github.com/dentys03/manual_duplex_linux

It installs a virtual printer which will print odd pages, display a window with instructions in which you click "proceed" after you flip the finished odd pages.

Issues with multiple pages per sheet can be solved by printing multiple pages per sheet to a file, then printing with the multiplexer.

This should be the simplest way and it's only dependency is your phisical printer.