# Manually duplex printing using HP LaserJet P1106

Tags: duplex-printing

I have recently brought HP LaserJet 1106 printer. I have installed it and it is working fine. But problem is I want to print on both side of the paper. But I am not getting any option to do that. I am not even getting the option to print only odd or even pages. Can any one help me in this regards.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: *Where* are you trying to print stuff from? This will play a *lot* with which options you get. For example, direct printing with `lpr` will have all the options available, the GTK file printing dialog will have some of those in the separators, other GUI programs may or may not offer all options.

Comment: sorry for late reply, I was out of station. Actually I was just searching print prom dash and opening the print option. From there I was printing. Can you please tell me where to find out from where I am printing. Thanks a lot for your prompt answer.

Comment: As I don't use Ubuntu, I can't really know what searching for print in dash does, so I can't say why it's not showing even/odd pages options :-\

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/173802/printer-manual-duplex-emulation

Comment: Thanks a lot @AmigableClarkKant but that is not working with unity, that is for gnome only.

Comment: I use Unity, I just tried it and it works just fine!