# Printing With Manual Duplex

Tags: 20.04, printing, canon, duplex-printing

I switched to Ubuntu, recently. I usually work with a printer that does not have support for automativ duplex (Canon MP495). I know the printer is old, but it works. I installed `gnome-manual-duplex` package manually as it is not supported in the latest versions. It does not work at all. What should I do?

Comment: does [this reference](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/printing-booklet-duplex.html.en) help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Printer Manual Duplex Emulation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/173802/printer-manual-duplex-emulation)

Answer (score 0):

Use Tea4CUPS.

https://wiki.debian.org/CUPSTea4CUPS

There are three methods to choose from.

Answer (score 0):

Check this virtual printer driver:

https://github.com/dentys03/manual_duplex_linux

It installs a virtual printer which will print odd pages, display a window with instructions in which you click "proceed" after you flip the finished odd pages.

This should be the simplest way and it's only dependency is your phisical printer's driver.